# Test class for controller is failing is production as SOQL on Period is not returning any records

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I have written a test class for a controller which is running in Sandbox, but failing in Production with the following Exception:

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

The line throwing the exception is:

```
fromDate = [SELECT StartDate FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' AND StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR].StartDate;
```

As it is running in sandbox, and Period is a Standard SObject, I am inclined to think that this may be caused due to certain settings. Is my thinking correct, and if so, which settings should I look into?

Comment: Are you using `@isTest(seeAllData=true)`? If so, that's generally a bad thing for this very reason (that is, data being different between environments). Please [edit] your question to include your test class (or at least relevant parts of it).

Comment: No, I am not. I am creating test data in the class itself. So it should not be a data issue as it is running successfully in sandbox.

Comment: You should look into validation rules and triggers that might be different on production (but specially the kind of metadata that can be created without the change set, including workflow rules and validation rules). They might be preventing your code from inserting the test data on production and not on sandbox (this happened to me multiple times because customers always forget to apply changes to sandbox first).

Comment: This controller is just used to display customized reports, so validation rules and triggers are not the issue. And the Period SObject is standard, with no other customization. So why should the query return results in Sandbox but not in Production?

Comment: Do you have a RunAs user for your test class? If so, does the RunAs user have permission in Production to create, edit and read the reports? IOW are you using the correct profile? Unless your class explicitly runs `without sharing`, this may be a permissions issue. Review your debug logs in detail to see what's being created.

Comment: I am using RunAs and the User has System Admin profile.

Comment: And where can I see and edit the permissions associated with Period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can create Period records in the test class, those are based on the existing data, regarding of the usage of seeAllData parameter.

You should check which Periods records are missing in production.

+
You can change the queries that might failed.
Instead:

```
fromDate = [SELECT StartDate FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' AND StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR].StartDate;
endDate = [SELECT EndDate FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' AND StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR].EndDate;
```

write:

```
for(Period p [select StartDate,EndDate from Period where type='Year and StartDate = THIS_FISCAL_YEAR limit 1]){
    fromDate = p.StartDate;
    endDate = p.EndDate;
}
```

Comment: I am not creating period records in the test class. I am just querying the existing records. And its standard, so I guess the issue is with some setting as the classes are identical in Sandbox and Production.